Webpage Password not working .htaccess & .htpasswd
I have an .htaccess file:
AuthUserFile  '/home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx/.htpasswd'
AuthName     'You Must Login To Enter The Members Only Area'
AuthType  Basic
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Require   valid-user

and a .htpasswd file, I encrypt the password using a algorithm based on CryptIt by Mathminded.
I have used this for years.
Since Godaddy migrated the site to CloudLinux 8 it doesn't work. I get the screen asking for the user name and password but it doesn't work it continually loops  asking for the username and password.
I checked the path using:<br/> <?php echo "Absolute path: ", getcwd(); ?><br/> the path is correct.  <br/>

I re-encrypted the .htpasswd file thinking is was corrupted in the migration. No help.  ,<br/>I did find out that the .thaccess file cannot contain double quotes it causes a internal Server Error.  <br/>
Any ideas on how I can get this to work again?
